# Create pandas dataframe from string

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, dataframe

I can easily build a pandas dataframe from a string that contains only **one** key value pair. For example:

```
string1 = '{"Country":"USA","Name":"Ryan"}'
dict1 = json.loads(string1)
df=pd.DataFrame([dict1])
print(df)
```

However, when I use a string that has more than one key value pair :

```
string2 = '{"Country":"USA","Name":"Ryan"}{"Country":"Sweden","Name":"Sam"}{"Country":"Brazil","Name":"Ralf"}'
dict2 = json.loads(string2)
```

I get the following error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

I am aware that string2 is not a valid JSON.

What modifications can I do on string2 *programmatically* so that I can convert it to a valid JSON **and then** get a dataframe output which is as follows:

```
| Country | Name |
|---------|------|
| USA     | Ryan |
| Sweden  | Sam  |
| Brazil  | Ralf |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the off chance that you  are getting data from elsewhere in the weird format that you described, following regular expression based substitutions can fix your json and there after you can go as per @Anton vBR 's solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

string2 = '{"Country":"USA","Name":"Ryan"}{"Country":"Sweden","Name":"Sam"}{"Country":"Brazil","Name":"Ralf"}'

#create dict of substitutions 
rd = { '^{' : '[{' , #substitute starting char with [
       '}$' : '}]',  #substitute ending char with ]
       '}{' : '},{'  #Add , in between two dicts
     }

#replace as per dict
for k,v in  rd.iteritems():
    string2 = re.sub(r'{}'.format(k),r'{}'.format(v),string2)

df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(string2))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Your error

The error says it all. The JSON is not valid. Where did you get that string2? Are you typing it in yourself?

In that case you should surround the items with brackets `[]` and separate the items with comma `,`.

Working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

string2 = '[{"Country":"USA","Name":"Ryan"},{"Country":"Sweden","Name":"Sam"},{"Country":"Brazil","Name":"Ralf"}]'

df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(string2))
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  Country  Name
0     USA  Ryan
1  Sweden   Sam
2  Brazil  Ralf
```

---

Interestingly, if you are extra observant, in this line here `df=pd.DataFrame([dict1])` you are actually putting your dictionary inside an array with brackers`[]`. This is because pandas DataFrame accepts arrays of data. What you actually have in your first example is an item in which case a serie would make more sense or `df = pd.Series(dict1).to_frame().T`.
 Or:

```
string1 = '[{"Country":"USA","Name":"Ryan"}]'  # <--- brackets here to read json as arr
dict1 = json.loads(string1)
df=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)
```

And if you understood this I think it becomes easier to understand that we need `,` to seperate the elements.

---

#### Alternative inputs

But let's say you are  creating this dataset yourself, then you could go ahead and do this:

```
data = [("USA","Ryan"),("Sweden","Sam"),("Brazil","Ralf")]
dict1 = [{"Country":i, "Name":y} for i,y in data] # <-- dictionaries inside arr
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Or:

```
data = [("USA","Ryan"),("Sweden","Sam"),("Brazil","Ralf")]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, columns=['Country','Name'])
```

Or which I would prefer to use a CSV-structure:

```
data = '''\
Country,Name
USA,Ryan
Sweden,Sam
Brazil,Ralf'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data))
```